# Google Now, gives walking directions for car rides

Tags: google-now

Google Now likes to tell me how to get somewhere on time, except it tells me how to do it by walking and suggests I leave 3-6 hours earlier than I should to realistically reach a destination. How do I change the directions from walking mode to driving mode or public transportation or other.

Insight appreciated